# Liquibase update could not Identify already executed change sets

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, liquibase

I am trying to run liquibase update on oracle database in command line and it couldn't able to identify the already executed change sets and it tries to start update from the beginning of the change log file

```
java -jar liquibase.jar --driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver --classpath=ojdbc14-11.2.0.3.0.jar --changeLogFile=ParentDBChangeLog.xml  --url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.25.XX.XXX:1521:ora11g" --username=xxxx --password=xxxxx update
```

It is getting failed from the first change set which tries to execute and the error which I got is

Error: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

How I can resolve this problem

Comment: Liquibase includes the file path of the changelog files to identify the changesets (along with id and author). Since you probably did not change id or author I am guessing your are running liquibase from a different PC (with different file paths for the changelog files). Or you moved you changelog files...

Comment: We had the same problem @jens is mentioning. Because we are using (relative) includes, the filename Liquibase stored in `DATABASECHANGELOG` was different depending on how the script was run (Maven, command line). We used the `logicalFilePath` attribute of the `databaseChangeLog` tag to ensure that Liquibase always used the same file regardless of the way it was executed.

Comment: logicalFilePath attribute configuration done and now the issue sorted. Thanks lot for the support given.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the database still contains the `DATABASECHANGELOG` and `DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK` tables and that they are appropriately populated (`DATABASECHANGELOG` should have one row of data for each of the changesets that has been applied to the database, and the `ID`, `AUTHOR`, and `FILENAME` columns should match the values in your changelog.xml).

I have seen many instances of well-meaning DBAs seeing those tables, not recognizing what they are, and removing them. I have also seen instances where someone was starting to introduce Liquibase but not everyone knows about that, and continues to use whatever process is alrady being used to manage schema change, and that process removes or alters those tables.